# Center diverging colors to zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

I would like to plot with diverging colors centered at 0 (red for postive values and blue for negative).
I tried normalizing the data with 0 as midpoint as suggested [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVf2R.png)

```
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

class MidpointNormalize(colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        colors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))

minzz = -4
maxzz = 1.5 

plt.contourf(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu_r',  norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0), vmin=minzz, vmax=maxzz)
plt.xticks()
plt.colorbar()
```

and I get this

[image]

It does not really follow the -4 to 1.5 range and how do I also increase the intervals especially to highlight more positive values.

Comment: The colorbar is all that is wrong in this picture and that is because you have no contours at 1.5.  Try setting your contour levels explicitly with the contour kwarg.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

`matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm` has been removed starting in Matplotlib 3.2, use `matplotlib.colors.TwoslopeNorm`, whose usage is identical to the removed norm.

---

The following drawing was done using [`matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm.html#matplotlib-colors-divergingnorm) and passing explicitly a list of `levels` to `plt.contourf`, because otherwise the contouring algorithm chooses intervals of the same length both for negative and positive values (and that is not what one usually wants).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import DivergingNorm

t = np.linspace(-3.1, 3.1, 63)
x, y = np.meshgrid(t, t)
r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
z = -2*np.cos(2*r)-1 # max = 1, min = -3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect(1)
img = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=[-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.25,0.5, 0.75, 1],
                  cmap='RdBu_r',
                  norm=DivergingNorm(0))
plt.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: center]